# "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column"

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to add comments to my posts on my Flask blog post website, but I always get this error - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column.

It says "no such column" even though I have created the db.Column, and also used "db.create_all()".

Here is a simplified version of my code:

routes.py file

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def post(post_id): # every post has a unique ID
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.query.all()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data)
        db.session.add(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("posts.post", post_id=post.id))

    image_file = url_for("static", filename=f"profile_pictures/{current_user.image_file}")
    return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, form=form, post=post, image_file=image_file)
```

models.py file

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Comment('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

forms.py file

```
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField("Title (optional)", validators=[Length(max=100)])
    content = TextAreaField("Content", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=500)])
    submit = SubmitField("Reply")
```

HTML code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
              {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                  {% if form.title.errors %}
                    {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in form.title.errors %}
                        <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                  {% else %}
                    {{ form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                  {% endif %}
                  <ul class="ml-4">
                    <li><small class="text-muted">Must be less than 500 characters long.</small></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
      
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ form.content.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                  {% if form.content.errors %}
                    {{ form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid", rows="7", cols="100") }}
                    {% for error in errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% else %}
                    {{ form.content(class="form-control", rows="7", cols="100") }}
                    <ul class="ml-4">
                      <li><small class="text-muted">This field must not be empty.</small></li>
                    </ul>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-info") }}
              </div>
            </form>
```

Please can someone help me - I've been stuck for days not knowing what to do.

Comment: Could you share the schema of your sqlite database? You can attach it to your question either as screenshot from a UI tool or access it via CLI and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the column on the database? If you say yes then check again your database name when connecting the SQLAlchemy, it should be error and it may be connected to the wrong DB.

Besides, you could check Flask migration (https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), also you have to add the config of sqlalchemy.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'mysql+pymysql://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DATABASE}?charset=utf8mb4'
```